# http GET request correspondent url with no argument

Tags: http, url, servlets, get

i have a servlet with doGet method implementation that read any parameter from client HttpServletRequest object, and should start automatically when user type his url. 
Now, if get request has parameter, the url for it should appear like:

```
http://myServer.com/myServlet?arg0=1&arg1=2
```

If i don't need that args, how is the url for perform a get request?

Answer (score 0):

If you will use doPost() method, then the arguments will not appear in the url.